# Magento how to check if user is signed in?

Tags: magento

How do I check if a user is signed in?

Like:

```
   <?php unless user_is_signed_in 
   echo "Please log in"
   end

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
```

or

```
Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
```

The second method calls the first - [see here](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php#L102)

---

So using the helper method as an example...

```
$isLoggedIn = Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
if (! $isLoggedIn) {
    echo "Please log in"; 
}
```

Comment: Can you add the unless statement and the echo? :)

Answer (score 0):

User the customer helper:

```
 $this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()
```